# Illegal value for primitive issue in JSON

Tags: lightning-aura-components, json

I have following JSON Format

lstSelectedIds-->

> [{"Id":"a0k1k000000QTPrAAO","Name":"00006144","User__c":"0051k000000wvYAAAY","User__r":{"Name":"Wissam Mahmassani","Id":"0051k000000wvYAAAY"}},{"Id":"a0k1k000000QTQcAAO","Name":"00006191","User__c":"0051k000000wvhqAAA","User__r":{"Name":"Nischitha Devaraj","Id":"0051k000000wvhqAAA"}}]

```
 [  
  {  
  "Id":"a0k1k000000QTPrAAO",
  "Name":"00006144",
  "User__c":"0051k000000wvYAAAY",
  "User__r":{  
     "Name":"Wissam Mahmassani",
     "Id":"0051k000000wvYAAAY"
  }
 },
  {  
  "Id":"a0k1k000000QTQcAAO",
  "Name":"00006191",
  "User__c":"0051k000000wvhqAAA",
  "User__r":{  
     "Name":"Nischitha Devaraj",
     "Id":"0051k000000wvhqAAA"
  }
 },
  {  
  "Id":"a0k1k000000QTfXAAW",
  "Name":"00007116",
  "User__c":"0051k000000wvuXAAQ",
  "User__r":{  
     "Name":"Ranjan Vasudeva",
     "Id":"0051k000000wvuXAAQ"
   }
}
]
```

cOMPONENT:

```
<aura:attribute name="LstOfAddedUser" type="List" description="Hold the list of added userUser Data"/>
```

Passing value in JS:

```
    action.setParams({
        "selectedIds":JSON.stringify(cmp.get("v.LstOfAddedUser")),
        "pageNumber": pageNumber,
        "pageSize": pageSize,

    });
```

Following Line causes error:

```
List<String> lstSelectedIds = (List<String>)System.JSON.deserialize(selectedIds, List<String>.class);
```

Class:

```
public static UserDataTableWrapper NextPagination(string selectedIds,Decimal pageNumber, Decimal pageSize){
    System.debug('lstSelectedIds-->'+selectedIds);
    List<String> lstSelectedIds = (List<String>)System.JSON.deserialize(selectedIds, List<String>.class);
```

wrapper class:

```
 public class UserDataTableWrapper {

          @AuraEnabled
           public Integer pageSize {get;set;}
          @AuraEnabled
          public Integer pageNumber {get;set;}
          @AuraEnabled
          public Integer totalRecords {get;set;}
          @AuraEnabled
            public Integer recordStart {get;set;}
            @AuraEnabled
            public Integer recordEnd {get;set;}
            @AuraEnabled
             public List<GSS_User_Data__c> contactList {get;set;}
        }
```

Error:  Illegal value for primitive

Comment: Can you include the debug output from "System.debug('lstSelectedIds-->'+selectedIds);"? That will really help in identifying the problem.

Comment: uPDATED THE code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that with JSON deserialisation, you get all or nothing. It either tries to fully deserialises your string into the object type you provide (in this case `List<String>`), or it does it completely untyped (with `JSON.deserializeUntyped()`). (There is also the strict mode which allows the process to ignore fields in the JSON which don't appear in the target type, but that's not your issue here).

Your string is a list of objects. So the a sensible interpretation of

```
System.JSON.deserialize(selectedIds, List<String>.class);
```

Would be that you want a list which looks a bit like this:

```
['{"Id":"a0k1k000000QTPrAAO","Name":"00006144","User__c":"0051k000000wvYAAAY","User__r":{"Name":"Wissam Mahmassani","Id":"0051k000000wvYAAAY"}}','{"Id":"a0k1k000000QTQcAAO","Name":"00006191","User__c":"0051k000000wvhqAAA","User__r":{"Name":"Nischitha Devaraj","Id":"0051k000000wvhqAAA"}}']
```

i.e. a list where each element is a still a JSON string representing an object. `JSON.deserialize()` just won't do that. It doesn't come across `String` in the target type and stop trying to deserialise.

In the context of all of your code, if you just want the ids, I would modify them in the Javascript controller like this:

```
action.setParams({
        "selectedIds":JSON.stringify(cmp.get("v.LstOfAddedUser").map(thisItem => thisItem.Id)),
        "pageNumber": pageNumber,
        "pageSize": pageSize,

});
```